# Las imágenes de los cursos en Moodle 3.11.15 no se ven

Tags: moodle

Revisé los permisos de las carpetas y están correctos, en la carpeta .data se ven también. Algunas imágenes son jpg y otras png Las
imágenes las subí desde el Moodle instalado en el servidor. He probado
en deshabilitar argumentos slash pero tampoco ha funcionado.

¿Me podéis ayudar?
Gracias

[Imagen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avEOb.png)
[Imagen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTRsE.png)
[Imagen3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msEvs.png)

Comment: Hola Alfredo, bienvenido, la preguntas/respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, y evitar recibir votos negativos, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.